# firefox to many dom elements table to css?

Tags: html, dom

im making a memberlist for my website, we got 500+ members and want them on 1 page. we used tables before but this makes many dom elements and firefox says it gets slow.

is there a way to make a list with 3/4 colums with css to avoid the nr. of dom elementst?

greets. stefan

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, the best way to display 500 elements is with Javascript. Having 500 records as JSON is not that big of a memory hog, totally acceptable. You'd have to make a dynamically updating table that takes the records from memory and displays only 40 rows at a time. You could also implement search etc in JS to make it more user friendly.